# `AndroidViewClient` doesn't update disappeared views?

Tags: android, automation, androidviewclient

When running my script using `AndroidViewClient` on some Android application I distinguish a view indicating the application is still loading.
I start a `While` loop with internal delay & refresh like this:

```
while LoadingApp is not None:  
    print "Application is still not ready.\nWaiting 5 seconds"  
    print The Application is still loading...  
    time.sleep(5)  
    refresh()
```

`refresh()` function performs entire views dump:

```
def refresh():  
    vc.dump(window='-1')  
    launcherIcon = vc.findViewById("fourier.milab:id/launcherIcon")  
    graphIcon = vc.findViewById("fourier.milab:id/graphIcon")  
    tableIcon = vc.findViewById("fourier.milab:id/tableIcon")  
    ...  
    LoadingApp = vc.findViewWithAttribute("text", u'Loading\nMiLAB')
```

Finally the application is completely On, `LoadingApp` view no more appear.

I suppose the `LoadingApp` variable to become `None` after the first `refresh()` is performed when the application is On but `LoadingApp` variable never got `None`, it remain holding the value received when application was loading.

So my `While` loop become infinite

I suppose this is `AndroidViewClient` bug.

If using `LoadingApp = vc.findViewWithAttributeOrRaise("text", u'Loading\nMiLAB')` it raises an exception on the first `refresh()` done when the application is On.

So `AndroidViewClient` now can't find this view (this is correct!) but it's container (the variable) still contains old, wrong, not updated value.

**UPD**:

My `While` loop code is

```
f = open('my_text.txt','w+')
while LoadingMiLAB is not None:
    print "MiLAB is still not ready.\nWaiting 5 seconds"
    print LoadingMiLAB
    for key, value in LoadingMiLAB.map.iteritems():
        print key, value
        f.write(key)
        f.write('\t')
        f.write(' '.join(map(str, value)))
        f.write('\n')
    f.write('\n\n\n')
    print "\n\n\n"
    time.sleep(5)
    refresh()
```

The output I receive is:

```
index   2
selected    f a l s e
checked f a l s e
clickable   f a l s e
package f o u r i e r . m i l a b
text    L o a d i n g 
 M i L A B
long-clickable  f a l s e
enabled t r u e
bounds  (550, 418) (729, 491)
content-desc    
focusable   f a l s e
focused f a l s e
uniqueId    i d / n o _ i d / 7
checkable   f a l s e
resource-id f o u r i e r . m i l a b : i d / r a t e T e x t V i e w
password    f a l s e
class   a n d r o i d . w i d g e t . T e x t V i e w
scrollable  f a l s e
```

This is what I receive when application is being loaded, when it is already loaded and even when I already closed the application at all.

So I think the problem is: `LoadingMiLAB` view data is not overwritten by `None` object received when the view is no more appear.

I set `DEBUG`, `DEBUG_RECEIVED` and `DEBUG_TREE` in `viewclient.py` to `TRUE`.

These are the only changes I made in `viewclient.py` or `adbclient.py` files.

I do not use `View.setVisibility(View.GONE)` or any other flag/parameter changed.

I use your `culebra` script with its default settings. The only parameter I changed there is the created (output) script file name and destination.

When I added `print vc.findViewWithText(u'Loading\nMiLAB').getVisibility()` code I saw `-1` while application is being loaded and the view presented.

When the application loaded (and the view disappeared) I received

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getVisibility'
```

I used `vc.findViewWithText(u'Loading\nMiLAB').getVisibility()`, not `vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'Loading\nMiLAB').getVisibility()`

because this raises error when the application is loaded and the view is no more appear.

I'm working on `Windows 7` OS PC

**UPD2**:

I added an exception into the `While` loop.

```
while LoadingMiLAB:
    print "MiLAB is still not ready.\nWaiting 5 seconds"
    time.sleep(5)
    refresh()
    try:
        LoadingMiLAB = vc.findViewWithText(u'Loading\nMiLAB')
    except EmptyLoadingMiLABException:
        print "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n"
```

Now my script exits the `While` loop and continues further on when `LoadingMiLAB` view is no more appear.

**FINAL UPD**

This was a my fault. My `refresh()` function actually created `local` variables, not refreshed the `global` views states. After declaring them as `global` my `refresh()` function works perfect!

Comment: Add a `print LoadingApp` to see what's there

Comment: Already did that.  It prints the values received first time when this view appeared on the screen even after several times `refresh()` done while the view already dissapeared

Comment: Also, why are you using `vc.findViewWithAttribute()` instead of `vc.findViewWithText()` ?

Comment: Well, I leaved this form from the day a learned different ways of finding the views according to their parameters, I'm sorry ;) Anyway, the phenomenon (bug) doesn't change when I use `vc.findViewWithText()`

Comment: try enabling DEBUG, DEBUG_RECEIVED and DEBUG_TREE in viewclient.py and capture the output

Comment: Set these 3 variables as `TRUE`. Now I see texts dumped to the `Command Prompt` changed when application become On (and changed again when I closed the application at all) but the `While` loop still continue running forever...

Comment: copy and paste the debug messages here

Comment: I think the problem is: LoadingMiLAB view data is not overwritten by `None` object received when the view is no more appear

Comment: Sorry, I can't read the log. Are you using `View.setVisibility(View.GONE)` to make the View disappear? Then, the View is still in the dump, so you should check for its visibility instead: `vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise('text').getVisibility()`

Comment: I updated the question above by adding the code and outputs answering your questions here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a my fault. My `refresh()` function actually created local variables, not refreshed the global views states. After declaring them as `global` my `refresh()` function works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I think you while loop should be more like (BTW, variables usually starts with lowercase, not to be confused with classes)

```
while True:
    print "MiLAB is still not ready.\nWaiting 5 seconds"
    time.sleep(5)
    refresh()
    try:
        vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'Loading\nMiLAB')
    except ViewNotFoundException:
        break
```

Comment: No. In this case it will catch the exception on `findViewWithTextOrRaise` and application will be terminated while I need it just to go out from the `While` loop. I tested this.

Comment: In addition it must be `While LoadingMiLAB` not `While TRUE` since I want to enter this loop only if `LoadingMiLAB` view is presented. This view is presented only if application has a problem with connecting to the external BT device....

Comment: Normally this view doesn't appear at all so I wish to enter this loop only in the case of a problem / delay connecting to the external paired BT device.